# Python Binance API Function Data Pull

Tags: python, pandas, api, binance

I am trying to write a function that will pull ticker information from Binance and put into a nice chart. I am using pandas and keep getting this error: pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Below is a portion of the code:

```py
def getminutedata(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol,interval, lookback + 'min ago CST'))
    
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:,6]
    frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    frame = frame.set_index('Time')
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    
    return frame


df = getminutedata('ADAUSDT', '1m', '30')
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because pandas dataframes are 2-dimensional, you can use at most **2** indexers to index a dataframe. You're using **3** (`:`, `:`, and  `6`).

Try changing this line:

```
frame = frame.iloc[:,:,6]
```

To this:

```
frame = frame.iloc[:,6]
```

Comment: Thank you Richardec! Doing what you suggested fixed that issue! I am now trying trying to solve a AttributeError. After I get that fixed I should be able to show a sample of the data frame. Has something to do with setting the index. Trying to learn panda. Will keep you posted!

Comment: @ITHawg no problem! If this solved your problem, there's no need to provide a sample dataframe, so don't worry. :)

Answer (score 0):

This Is the correcte one

```
def getminutedata(symbol, interval, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol,interval, lookback))
    
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:6]
    frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    frame = frame.set_index('Time')
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    
    return frame
```